# Testing stdout logger with PyTest

Tags: python, pytest

I would like to test my logger in PyTest. My logger is currently setup to log to stdout.

My question is how do I capture the logs to stdout within PyTest? For example on initialisation my logger prints the following:

```
{"logger_level": "error", "event": "logging_initialised", "logger": "log.logger", "level": "info"}
```

How could I check that the levels within the json are correct and it has indeed printed this?

Thanks for help!

Comment: Use the [logcap fixture](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/logging.html#caplog-fixture).

Comment: Thanks Klaus for the pointer!

Comment: Update: it is now `caplog` and not `logcap` .